# any Tex template for this arxiv article?

Tags: sourcecode, arxiv

I am from optimization and control society. I would like upload a paper in a non-description way, probably, like.

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.00527.pdf

Could you please help figure out how the format can be generated ? It appears easy and common since many other papers share nearly same layout.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can download the source file from arXiv.

Comment: Yeah, looking at [all formats](http://arxiv.org/format/1604.00527v1) for that article will give you the source to download...which is a great way to learn a lot of nifty TeX-nical tricks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TeX file template like arXiv preprints](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422322/tex-file-template-like-arxiv-preprints).The solution is the same: download the source file.