# TeX file template like arXiv preprints

Tags: arxiv

I want to basically upload a research preprint to arXiv. I want my paper to exactly look like this paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.00283.pdf) including the hyperlinks in the bibliography.

Can someone please tell me how the scratch tex file should look like to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Both on the [APS web page](https://journals.aps.org/revtex) as well on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1) you can find the class `revtex4-1` as well as documentation and templates.

Comment: You can see the source of arxiv papers if you want to. https://arxiv.org/format/1707.00283v1. The `.tex` file is available in the Source file.

Comment: @Troy though I wouldn't suggest to look at _that_ paper. They use `revtex4`, which has been outdated since 2010...

Comment: @campa I agree. And they use `eqnarray`. *shudders*

Comment: Thanks for the information guys. What do you recommend then? I knoweqnarray is to old. Where can I find the revtex4-1 class?

Comment: @sbp What's your distribution (MikTeX/TeXLive)? It's available on CTAN regardless (see .@campa's first comment).

Comment: Yeah realised that!

Answer (score 3):

You can always download the source files and see what the author did (via the "other formats link" from the abstract page). In this instance, you can see that they did:

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,twocolumn,showpacs,preprintnumbers,amsmath,amssymb,footinbib]{revtex4}
...
\usepackage{xcolor}% coloured text
\usepackage[breaklinks=true,colorlinks,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 1):

This bibliography style is actually highly desirable, but the source file on ArXiv doesn't provide any insight how to produce it, but adding *by hand* the required `\href{<urlstring>}{<paperref>}`.

To fix this question with BibTeX, I have edited *by hand* a`.bst` file (a custom one produced by the `makebst` script). You can download it from https://www.edpif.org/misc/latex/customen-href.bst.
In this file you can find the (slight) modifications, marked by `%%%%%%`, next to lines 463 and 1144.

I post here an example of output, but a version with functional links is available at https://www.edpif.org/misc/latex/customen-href.pdf

[image]